# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'control')

Tags: html, json, web

I have a map made with openstreetmap, when loading my page where my map is located, at first it does not show the markers as well as the route, but then in the next search if it loads I would like support as to why this is due in the console I get this error "I have a map made with open street map, when loading my page where my map is located, at the beginning it does not show the markers as well as the route, but then in the next search it does load"

function initMapOpen(latitud_o, longitud_o,latitud_d, longitud_d,idEstado)
{

```
var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.src = 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js';
document.body.appendChild(script2);

map = L.map('map').setView([-12.069900, -77.031695], 11);
mapLink = "<a href='https://openstreetmap.org'>OpenStreetMap</a>";
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: 'Leaflet &copy; ' + mapLink + ', contribution', maxZoom: 15 }).addTo(map);

origen = {lat: latitud_o, lng: longitud_o};
destino = {lat: latitud_d, lng: longitud_d};

if(idEstado == 2 || idEstado == 5)
{
    route = {lat: latitud_o, lng: longitud_o};
}else
{
    route = {lat: 0, lng: 0};
}

icon_o = "public/img/markers/CENTRALS.png";
icon_d = "public/img/markers/PROVINCIA.png";

if(idEstado == 2 || idEstado == 5)
{
    icon_r = "public/img/markers/carro.png";
}else
{
    icon_r = "xd";
}

var gps;
var html8 = '';

if(icon_r == "xd")
{
    //alert("end")
    gps = destino;
}else
{
    //alert("route")
    gps = route;
}

var startIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: icon_o,
    iconSize: [50, 50]
});

var endIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: icon_d,
    iconSize: [50, 50]
});

var taxiIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'public/img/markers/carro.png',
    iconSize: [30, 30]
});

if (idEstado == 2 || idEstado == 5){

    var marker = L.marker(origen, { icon: taxiIcon }).addTo(map);

}

L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
                    L.latLng(origen),
                    L.latLng(destino)
    ],
    createMarker: function (i, waypoint,n) {
        var marker = L.marker(waypoint.latLng, {
            draggable: true,
            icon: endIcon
        });

        return marker;
    }
    }).on('routesfound', function (e) {
            var routes = e.routes;
            console.log(routes);

            if (idEstado == 2 || idEstado == 5){

                e.routes[0].coordinates.forEach(function (coord, index) {
                    timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        comienzo(marker);
                    }, 3000 * index)
                })
                //setInterval(comienzo(marker),3000);
            }

    }).addTo(map);
```

}

I need it to load from the start